# How can I add edits to a file committed in the past?

Tags: git, git-commit

I committed a list of edits, and then I developed a new feature and committed again. Now I discovered that another edit needs to go into the first commit, how can I do this with git? Since I committed twice I cannot use `--amend`

Comment: are your changes pushed already?

Comment: No, actually they aren't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `git rebase -i`, selecting to edit the given commit. Note that doing so for an already pushed commit is discouraged, as it might delete your colleagues' work, so only do that if they agree (and synchronize their repositories).

You can also create a `fixup` commit that might be squashed later:

```
git commit --fixup=hash_of_the_commit_to_change
# later:
git rebase -i --autosquash ...
```

The same caveat applies as above to the later command, but the commits can be created without fear.

Comment: assuming they are not pushed yet, your answer is correct.